# Change format date in french

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to put the dynamic date in French format but I can't.
it's in an ios program with the SwiftUI language

Text(Date().formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted))

Comment: This will return the date formatted to the user's locale. In order to force a different format you need to use an actual `DateFormatter` and set the locale like this: `Formatter returns the users preferred format by default.  You can change this behavior by setting the locale like this `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")`.

Comment: @Yrb the question is about SwiftUI

Comment: We use DateFormatters all of the time in SwiftUI. `.formatted()` is only available in iOS 15+. It, to my knowledge, [doesn't allow you to change locales](https://sarunw.com/posts/new-formatters-in-ios15/#conclusion).

Comment: @Yrb In theory you could but it doesn't work. `Text(Date(), format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .complete, time: .none, locale: .init(identifier: "fr_FR")))`

Comment: I meant using an actual 'DateFormatter', not trying to put a `.locale` into `Text(Date().formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted))` .

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Thats exactly what I said. It should work in theory but it doesn't.

Comment: ha, yeah, sorry I just copy and pasted the code without reading your post thoroughly. I'll delete my comment shortly.